# Self syntax in iPhone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

What is the difference between the following two approaches for the `self` syntax to access the object properties:-

Approach 1:-

```
    self.effortView = [[EffortView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    self.effortView.effortTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 300, 420) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Approach 2:-

```
    effortView = [[EffortView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    effortView.effortTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 300, 420) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

`effortView` is defined as a property, and synthesized, to the Class addressed as `self` in *Approach 1*. Both of the approaches work.

I am using Xcode 4.0 iPhone SDK 4.3 on Mac 10.6.6.

Please enlighten me.

Thank you All

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first syntax:

```
self.effortView = [[EffortView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
self.effortView.effortTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 300, 420) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

you are accessing both ivars through their accessor methods (usually, `effortView` to get, `setEffortView` to set).

In the second syntax:

```
effortView = [[EffortView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
effortView.effortTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 300, 420) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

you are accessing the `effortView` ivar directly (pointer assignment), while you are accessing `effortTableView` through its property accessor.

The difference is that using an accessor you obtain additional behavior. Like, with the standard `set` accessors generated by the `@synthesize` keyword for a `retain` property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject* property;
```

you get automatic retain count management (i.e., retain count will be automatically incremented on the assigned object; if the ivar had already a value, the object pointed to will have its retain count decreased). What this implies is that in your first example, you are causing 2 memory leaks. Indeed, (if the properties are declared as `retain` property) assigning to them will increase their retain count; but `[[alloc] init]` already gives back an object with a retain count of 1, so you don't need to increment it once more. Correct would be:

```
self.effortView = [[[EffortView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] autorelease];
self.effortView.effortTableView = [[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 300, 420) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
```

Overall, properties make much easier to deal with retain count management and are the suggested way to go with it, but you have to be aware of their "retain count" semantics and account for that.

I would suggest [this article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2712/using-properties-in-objective-c-tutorial) as an interesting reading.

Comment: Do you mean, that when I use `self.effortView` the `effortView` would set itself again, i.e. the control flow of the running program would keep hitting `@synthesize effortView` the times I call it. And in the second syntax the property will be set only once.

Comment: What I mean is that @synthesize will generate two selectors: `-(yourClass*)property` and `-(void)setProperty:(yourClass*)value`. When you use the properties, those functions are called to get and set a value. Xcode debugger graphically represents that function call by highlighting the `@synthesize` directive in your code, and that actually means that the automatically generated methods are being executed.

Comment: Thanks @sergio That was nice tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If the property is declared like this

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) EffortView *effortView;
```

both approaches are equivalent. In the case the property is declared like this

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) EffortView *effortView;
```

the code `[[EffortView alloc] init...];` first generates a retained EffortView instance and then the 'assignment' `self.effortView = ...` retains this instance again. Therefore to balance the retain count you have to release the generated instance.

Answer (score 0):

The former uses the accessors methods generated by the synthesize statement.

The latter accesses the variable directly.

Answer (score 0):

`self.effortView` uses the accessor methods generated by `@synthesize` to get and set the property, while `effortView` accesses the instance variable directly. Inside the class where the property is defined, the difference is most important when considering the setter: it automatically takes care of memory management. So if you've done this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) EffortView *effortView;
```

then the two approaches have different results. Approach 1 leaks in this case, as the setter retains the object and you `+alloc` it without a balanced `-release`.

Comment: When a setter for a property is created using @synthesize, the property first calls the autorelease method, which does not actually means that the property is released. Thus, approach one leaks. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No. The property method calls `retain`. You passed it an object you created with `+alloc`. Therefore, the code that owns this object has claimed ownership twice.

Comment: Yes, the property method calls `retain` but only after `autorelease` is called. I referred 
  http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

Comment: Take a closer look at how their setters are implemented: they call `-autorelease` on a different object (the previous value of the property, whatever that was) than retain. Therefore you are still in the situation where you've over-retained your new object.

Comment: if I use `self.effortView = myTempView` the RHS would be retained and not the value stored by `effortView`, it was `autoreleased`.